# Using paypal to purchase documents

Tags: paypal

I would like to use paypal to allow clients to purchase documents
I would like to list a document then the client clicks the buy now button.
Once payment is successful I would like paypal to return to my site so that I can attach a reference number that the client would input to be able to download the document

Is this possible

Thank you in advance

Lional

Comment: Check the Documentation for Paypal [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Paypal Express Checkout for Digital goods](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/gs_expresscheckout/).This service helps you streamline the checkout process for a buyer. The payment experience is on paypal.com (a redirection from the merchant's site) and then the buyer is returned to the merchant's site for payment confirmation. To use this service, the merchant must have a PayPal merchant account.

Digital goods are items such as e-books, music files, and digital images distributed in electronic format. The buyer can conveniently purchase digital goods.